# some errors when Im using ( join on) in sql

Tags: sql

Im trying to use join on in my sql to link between three tables but still have errors

[image]

when I'm trying to retrieve:
 (Aminah’s lecturer and subject)
i did this but still have errors

```
 SELECT c.SUBJECT1,c.SUBJECT2,c.SUBJECT3,l.NAME
FROM
  STUDENT s 
  JOIN COURSE c
   ON c.COURSE = s.COURES
   JOIN LECTURER l
   ON l.LECT_ID =c.LECT1 AND c.LECT2 AND c.LECT3 
WHERE s.NAME = 'Aminah' AND c.SUBJECT1 = c.LECT1 AND c.SUBJECT2 = c.LECT2 AND c.SUBJECT3 = c.LECT3
```

also same thing when i am trying to show:
(Subject that teach by Ahmad)
i am a beginner andit is still hard to me with using (join on) 
i hope some one help me

Answer (score 0):

I think you want multiple joins, like this:

```
select c.subject1, c.subject2, c.subject3,
       l1.name as name_1, l2.name as name_2, l2.name as name_2
from student s join
     course c
     on s.course = c.course left join
     lecturer l1
     on c.lect_1 = l1.lect_id left join
     lecturer l2
     on c.lect_2 = l2.lect_id left join
     lecturer l3
     on c.lect_3 = l3.lect_id
where s.name = 'Aminah';
```

You should also know that this is a really bad data model.  It is suspicious whenever you have "arrays" (such as courses) that are spread across columns.  These should actually be in separate rows to be better suited to SQL.